# Good books on Algorithms for a math major without any programming experience?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, book-recommendation, computational-mathematics, advice

I couldn't find this question anywhere else so it may not be apt.

I am an undergraduate mathematics major and during my discrete math class I really enjoyed the study of algorithms and recursive functions. I have looked at very few computer languages and not in to much depth (it wasn't within class just on my own) but I would consider myself as someone who has no real understanding of programming.

Now I am aware that there are certain fields in the study of algorithms that do not require much knowledge of computer science directly.Is something like the theory of recursive functions have a similar flavor to algorithms?

*Question 1: Is it possible to engage in a study of algorithms from a mathematical perspective without having taken computer sciences classes?*

*Question 2: Are there any good books you guys can recommend which someone with my background would be able to follow without too much trouble?*

Thanks a lot in advance and any answer is appreciated.

Comment: On the programming side, I would recommend trying to learn Python and also learn a [*CAS*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems) as you can get up to speed quickly. For books, maybe check out: Introduction to Algorithms 
by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein and also Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science by Graham, Knuth, Patashnik

Comment: Yes, it is fully possible to study algorithms, and more generally, theoretical computer science, without being able to program, as long as you understand how algorithms work and are able to write these down in pseudocode, at least when necessary. However, much motivation and intuition may be gained by actually learning how to program as well, and being able to program will benefit you throughout most of mathematics in general (in fact, I can actually argue that I would never have developed as much as I have mathematically if it weren't for taking programming courses).

Comment: As for books, you can check out the usual "bibles" by Sipser, Papadimitriou and the more modern tome by Arora and Barak. They all are more mathematical than programming-related, and cover algorithms and such (automata and complexity theory) from a more abstract perspective than the concrete "solve this shortest path by Dijkstra's algorithm" you have probably encountered in disc. math. It's sort of a world of its own…

Comment: @A.Sh Thanks a lot for the comment. Do you know if Arora and Barak have any prerequisites other than Discrete Math?

Comment: "An Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms" by Robert Sedgewick and Philippe Flajolet might fit your needs.  There is very little code in it.  But learning to program is a good idea too.

Comment: I'd say the prerequisites would be calculus, perhaps first courses in linear algebra, discrete math, probability, and perhaps also algorithms (as in a full course specialized on construction and analysis of algorithms)…perhaps the suggestion by Moo of Cormen et al (which is yet another "bible") would be a good place to start for the last prereq. Arora-Barak is a self-contained book, and is made to last for a long time. It starts off easy and then gradually grows heavier by the chapter. Most prereqs. are accounted for in the appendix. There's also an incomplete version of the text on the web.

Comment: Here's an old draft of the book, which you can check out for yourself: http://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/book.pdf There are errors strewn about it though, so beware for that. The final book lies at the same level as the draft, but with much less errors :)